NUXT UI Modal component has twitchy animation
In NuxtUI Modal component has twitchy animation.
This problem occurs due to scroll slider in browser, when I open Modal, scroll slider dissapers and modal window move to right, so when I close Modal it moves to left cuz scroll slider appears.
VOD: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUmSYBXVYaQ

     <div>
        <span class="other_types">Скриншоты</span>
        <UModal v-model="isOpen">
          <div class="flex justify-center items-center p-2">
            <img :src="selectedImage" alt="" />
          </div>
        </UModal>
        <div class="flex flex-wrap gap-3 mt-2">
          <img
            :src="apiBase + screenshot.original"
            alt="Studio"
            class="w-52 mt-2"
            v-for="screenshot in info.screenshots"
            @click="modalScreenShotMiddleware(screenshot.original)"
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <span class="other_types">Озвучки</span>
        <p class="mt-2">{{ info.fandubbers.join(", ") }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


I checked some other UI libraries, for instance shadcn or radix-vue, and there Modal works fine.
Please help me to fix this.

Could you please provide a [repro]? It's hard to help with just this.

heres example, shadcn has good animation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUmSYBXVYaQ

Hm, should be doable to override the sidebar behavior with some CSS.

I dont get it, can you do some examples
